# Run qgis server with nginx in docker container (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops, qgis

I need to run QGIS server together with NGINX. I have to setup the environment using docker-compose. I am using the docker-compose file as mentioned in the comment.
And nginx.conf as below -

```
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
#  error_log /etc/nginx/error/error.log warn; #./nginx/error.log warn;
  client_max_body_size 20m;   
  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xxx;
 #   return 301 https://localhost:80$request_uri;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
 #  return 301 https://localhost:8008;
     }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;    
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xxx; # localhost;    
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_tickets off;   
    #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key;   
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:EECDH:EDH:!MD5:!RC4:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!CAMELLIA:!ECDSA:!DES:!DSS:!3DES:!NULL;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    keepalive_timeout 70;

    location /qgis/ {

            proxy_pass http://qgis:8080;              
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            
        }
 
   }
    
  }
```

After `docker-compose up` the nginx container is always in restarting state. `docker-compose logs` are as below -

```
web_server_1   | 2021/05/12 16:53:45 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "qgis" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
web_server_1   | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "qgis" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this as `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:

  web_server:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./mime.types:/etc/nginx/conf/mime.types
    - ./public:/data/www
    - ./tile_cache:/tile_cache
    - ./logs:/logs
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    restart: always
    networks:
      tile_network:
        aliases: 
          - webserver   

  qgis_server:
    image: camptocamp/qgis-server
    volumes:
    - ./qgisserver:/etc/qgisserver/
    restart: always
    environment:
     - QGIS_PROJECT_FILE=/etc/qgisserver/project.qgs
    networks:
      tile_network:
        aliases: 
          - qgis
```

Add in you `nginx.conf` the following location:

```
        location /qgis/ {


            proxy_pass http://qgis/;
            
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            
        }
```

So you have a web server, that hide the QGIS Server and show it on ULR `localhost/qgis`